# SpinButton - vba

Tags: vba, excel

When I hide and unhide the rows I find my SpinButton in there place with the hight= 18; but the problem when I close my workbook and I open it the hight of the SpinButton becom 0.
**Note:** When I open my workbook I need to have some rows hiden, that's why I hede them for each opening of the workbook.
Which property should I use to the SpinButton?

The problem is from What version of office, I try the same think in office 2016 it works without problem, but in my laptop I have office 2010.
[image]

Comment: How about `Height`?

Comment: I use this code `Private Sub intiliserleSpinButton() 'Height SpinButton1.Height = 18 SpinButton2.Height = 18 SpinButton3.Height = 18 SpinButton4.Height = 18 SpinButton5.Height = 18 SpinButton6.Height = 18 SpinButton7.Height = 18 SpinButton8.Height = 18 End Sub` **But they appear One over the other.**

Comment: I find that the problem is from What version of office, I try the same think in office 2016 it works without problem, but in my laptop I have office 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your Workbook.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    'do the stuff for the spin button here

End Sub
```

In "'do the stuff", put the code, that controls the size of your spin buttons. It should work.

Edit:
Select one of the control elements and do the following:
left mouse button>properties. Then choose move and size with cells. Or try the other options.

[image]

Comment: I call this sub in the  **Workbook_Open()**
`Private Sub intiliserleSpinButton()
 'Height
    SpinButton1.Height = 18
    SpinButton2.Height = 18
    SpinButton3.Height = 18
    SpinButton4.Height = 18
    SpinButton5.Height = 18
    SpinButton6.Height = 18
    SpinButton7.Height = 18
    SpinButton8.Height = 18


   
End Sub`
**But they appear One over the other.**

Comment: I applied this properties from the beginning. I have always the same problem.